# I am having trouble printing out an instance method and a class method

Tags: java, methods, instance, class-method

So the code I am working with is supposed to check if a number is prime and then I need to print out the result of, whether it is prime? From my instance and class method. I am having trouble because I feel like I set up everything correctly, but I am getting no results when I run the program. I will take any advice. Be easy on me this is my first year programming.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner myInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        int someValue = myInput.nextInt();

        MyInteger myInt = new MyInteger(someValue);
        System.out.println("Testing instance method:");
        System.out.println(myInt.isPrime());
        System.out.println("Testing class method:");
        System.out.println(MyInteger.isPrime(myInt));
    }
}

class MyInteger {
    private int value;

    public MyInteger(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public boolean isPrime() {
        int sqrt = (int) Math.sqrt((double)value);
        for(int i = 2; i <= sqrt; i++) {
            if (value % i == 0) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean isPrime(MyInteger myInt) {
        return myInt.isPrime();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "no result"? Nothing prints at all? Please show what you're actually seeing when you run the program.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Comment: @GhostCat: actually, this **is** a valid MCVE. I've up-voted the question accordingly, and encourage you to do the same. I'm guessing that he's running it wrong.

Comment: The program is OK and, once you type in a number and hit enter, the results are there.

Comment: `public static boolean isPrime(MyInteger myInt) {return myInt.isPrime();}` makes no sense since instead of `MyInteger.isPrime(myInt)` we can simply write `myInt.isPrime();`. That method should probably take `int` and not `MyInteger` as argument, then wrap it in `MyInteger` and return result of its `isPrime`, like `return new isPrime(intValue).isPrime();`.

Comment: "getting no results" doesn't sound mcve to me...

Comment: That's the problem statement, and yes that is deficient, but the code itself fulfills MCVE requirements.

Comment: Anyway your code seems to be *somehow* working https://ideone.com/SxSUSf. Only thing which may cause "not working" impression I can think of now is possible lack of any value in standard input. In other words your code may simply be waiting for user input at `int someValue = myInput.nextInt();` line before it moves on with rest of code.

Answer (score 0):

Program is working fine, and everything is good, i think you are not giving input to the program.

Run the program, write any number on the screen/console, press enter, you will see output then.

Here is the working screenshot: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Your class method has no benefit in the way you write it.

you have to pass an `int` instead of `MyInteger`

Like this:

```
public static boolean isPrime(int integer) {
    MyInteger myInt = new MyInteger(integer);
    return myInt.isPrime();
}
```

> And also your code is working